# Is it possible to put existing custom layout into another layout. Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Is it possible to put existing custom layout into another layout(in xml) in Android?

Comment: @Axarydax thanks for your answer, can you show me some example?

Comment: ya use  <include
                layout="@layout/your_existing_layout" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
<include  layout="@layout/customlayout" android:id="@+id/id" />
```